# Different icon for appBar back button in the whole app

Tags: flutter, dart

When navigating between pages in flutter, if the second page has an AppBar, by default the `AppBar` comes with an `IconButton` to go back to the previous page. Is there a way to set a custom icon for that IconButton that is different than the one provided by default by Flutter and will be applied to every other page? Kind of like a custom `AppBarTheme`?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `BackButton` and handling it by yourself, using:

```dart
AppBar(        
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: Navigator.canPop(context)
        ? IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 47,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          )
        : null,
);
```

Comment: I know this, what I am talking about is making a kind of custom AppBarTheme so that every page comes with the custom icon by default without having to specify the leading every time in the app bar

Comment: @BorisKayi have you solved this? please answer

Comment: @LalitRawat unfortunately I have not